# How to change every element in a list of list that is convertible into integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a simple list of list

```
a = [['A','10'],['B','30']]
```

How do I change it so that only those elements that can be converted into an integer is converted into an integer.

So I am hoping to get

```
a = [['A',10],['B',30]]
```

Comment: Are the inner sublists always of size 2? And are always the string you want to convert to integer at index 1?

Comment: If your numbers are always **positive integers**,

    `new_a = [[int(v) if v.isdigit() else v for v in l] for l in a]`

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a try except block as follows.

```
def try_convert_int(val):
    try:
        return int(val)
    except ValueError:
        return val

a = [['A','10'],['B','30']]

out = [[try_convert_int(item) for item in row] for row in a]
print(out) #[['A', 10], ['B', 30]]
```